# uvcvideo failed to query (GET_INFO)

Tags: uvc

When I boot Ubuntu 18.04 I get this error in the register:

```
uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
```

My web camera works fine.

What could be the cause of this  message?

Comment: You might be able to still have a working camera and block the uvcvideo module, or you will have to live with the fact the developers are chatty loggers.